# Quantidade de co-ocorrencias em uma matriz

Tags: algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Tenho uma duvida mais matemática do que computacional. 
Supomos que temos uma matriz quadrada M de dimensão `n²`, onde `n` é qualquer inteiro maior que zero. Percorrendo essa matriz, atribuindo `j` como índice das linhas e `i` aos índices das colunas, qual a complexidade do algoritmo se eu considerar `ij` somente quando `i>j`?
Abaixo a demostração do algoritmo:

```
for i=0; i<n-1; i++:
  for j=i+1; i<n; j++:
    if i>j:
      ////cont..
```

Quero saber qual a função para determinar, a partir de `n`, quantas vezes o `if` será verificado. Em outras palavras, quantos elementos há na matriz triangular abaixo da diagonal.

*Sei que é uma pergunta muito besta, mas esqueci completamente como encontrar essa função.

Comment: `(n-1)**2/2`, ou algo muito próximo, eu diria.

Comment: Aliás, acho que tem algo de estranho. No seu código, você altera o valor de `i` na iteração intenta. Com isso, você só irá executar `x` passos e cairá fora dos dois laços. Sem falar que você começa a falar de `n` e na código introduz `x`, que está fora de contexto

Comment: É! Alguns erros no algoritmo, agora que vi, mas ele é só um exemplo do problema, o `x` é o mesmo que `n` e no segundo for é `j<x` e `j++` e não `i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu `if` já foi desenhado para que ele seja executado apenas em uma parte da matriz de domínio.

Considere que o seu domínio consista da seguinte matriz:

```
d s s s s
i d s s s
i i d s s
i i i d s
i i i i d
```

Onde os elementos em `d` são os elementos da diagonal principal, os elementos em `i` são os elementos da porção inferior à diagonal principal e os elementos em `s` são os elementos da porção superior à diagonal principal.

A sua iteração cobre perfeitamente apenas os elementos em `i`, sem sobrar nem faltar. Portanto, seja qual fosse o propósito do `if` (que aparentemente garante que o elemento está necessariamente em `s`, considerando que o laço externo é mudança de coluna e o interno, de linha), ele se tornou inútil devido ao como o laço foi desenhado.

Independente da utilidade do `if`, foi questionado a respeito de quantas vezes ele iria ser avaliado. Ora, se ele cobre exatamente os elementos em `i`, basta contar quantas casas tem `i`. Na primeira coluna m, `i` tem zero elementos, em seguida tem 1, 2, até que no `n`-ésimo e última coluna ele tem `n-1` elementos.

Portanto, ele é o seguinte somatório:

```
Área(i) = 1 + 2 + ... + (n - 1)
```

Que dá `n*(n-1)/2`. Se você está usando alguma linguagem de programação que faz divisão inteira, então tome cuidado para garantir que a multiplicação é feita antes da divisão. Por que esse cuidado? Porque talvez `(n-1)` não seja par, assim como talvez `n` também não o seja, mas certamente `n*(n-1)` é par.

Comment: é essa a função que eu queria achar mesmo `n*(n-1)/2`. O mais próximo que eu havia chegado foi `(n²÷2)−log2(n)`, mas o valor nem sempre é inteiro e como sabemos, a matriz triangular inferior sempre vai possuir um numero de elementos (i) inteiro.

Comment: @FranciscoSobrinho `n/2 ~~= log2(n)` para valores pequenos. Não se esqueça de, estando certa a resposta, marcá-la como aceita no ✅ para que outras pessoas possam aproveitar do conhecimento também